# Select an option from a dependent drop box Selenium web driver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, driver

My application must be used in IE. I am automating test in which the script first has to select an option in 1st drop-box, "Category", to get category-associated options displayed in 2nd drop-box, "Name". Script then selects an option in "Name", and an associated page will display.
"Name" does not have any options until a selection is made in "Category". HTML source:

```
<select id="drop_Category">
   <option value =""/>
   <option value = "Category1">
     Text - Category1
   <option value = "Category2">
     Text - Category2
<select id="drop_Name">
```

After option "Category1" selected, HTML source changes to:

```
<select id="drop_Category">
   <option value =""/>
   <option value = "Category1">
     Text - Category1
   <option value = "Category2">
     Text - Category2
<select id="drop_Name">
   <option value =""/>
   <option value = "C1_Name1">
     Text - C1_Name1
   <option value = "C1_Name2">
     Text - C1_Name2
   <option value = "C1_Name3">
     Text - C1_Name3
```

For the script to select "Category1" and "C1_Name3", my first version of code is:

```
//Select option in drop-box "Category"
stringText = "Category1";
var dropCategory = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Category")));
dropCategory.SelectByText(stringText);

//Select option in drop-box "Name"
stringText = "C1_Name3";
var dropName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Name")));
dropName.SelectByText(stringText);
```

This code did not work because the list in "Name" has not been loaded and script cannot find option with text "C1_Name3", so I added implicit wait. Wait did not help, so I tried to catch the exception. This is 2nd version of code:

```
//Select option in drop-box "Category"
stringText = "Category1";
var dropCategory = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Category")));
dropCategory.SelectByText(stringText);

//Select option in drop-box "Name"
stringText = "C1_Name3"
try
{
   var dropName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Name")));
   dropName.SelectByText(stringText);   
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
   var dropName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Name")));
   dropName.SelectByText(stringText);   
}
```

It worked but still crashed sometimes due to InvalidSelectorException or StaleElementReferenceException  exceptions. I don't know what to do to get this work consistently. Also, I am new in the field so I am not sure if this is bad practice to write code as in my 2nd version. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: If the element takes time to appear and to be useable, why are you not using explicit waits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial Approach**

Typically (in my experience) a sleep time is required in addition to the wait-time approach; so try combining the two.

For example, I would try looping until the element you want is found. *Pseudo-code* follows:

```
boolean found = false;
while (!found) {
try
{
   var dropName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Name")));
   dropName.SelectByText(stringText);
   found = true;  
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
   var dropName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("drop_Name")));
   dropName.SelectByText(stringText); 
   //do a short sleep here e.g. 500ms depending on the speed of your site  
}

}
```

From the [documentation on the InvalidSelectorException](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html), that exception is also thrown when "the selector which is used to find an element does not return a WebElement." So catching NoSuchElementException should be enough.

**Alternate Approach**

- From your question `<select id="drop_Name">` exists in the code from the start.
- Therefore `driver.findElement` will *always* find a WebElement by ID `drop_Name`
- The difference is that *until you select `Category1`*, `drop_Name` has no `<option>` values.
- Therefore you could try the following wait function:

(Note: code is in Java; can be easily ported to C#)

```
private static void waitUntilOptionsLoad() {
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElement(By.id("drop_Name"))
                        .findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        if (options.size() > 0 ) { 
            System.out.println("More than one option tag found; therefore options have loaded");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I combined 2 approaches: use the wait function first to ensure the "Name" list loads, then try the selection in "Name" and catch any other exceptions (without "try..catch", sometimes there is error "Element is no longer valid"). It works. I have a loop of more than 20 tests of this type run well.